# Combining records but other columns have different values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wanted to combine the same values in CATEGORY in this table, but as you can see the dates in the DATE column do not match up. Is there a way I can ignore this and just take the latest date in SQL?

Comment: I don't know what you meant by "Combine the same values", can you explain a little more please.

Comment: Under CATEGORY, there are two A's. I wish to combine the two records.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CATEGORY, SIDE, sum(QUANTITY),sum(PRICE)
FROM table_name
group by 1,2
```

Basically, exclude the date column and the category can be grouped easily.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like:

```
SELECT CATEGORY, SIDE, Sum(QUANTITY) AS TOTALQUANTITY, PRICE, Max(DATE) AS LASTDATE 
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY CATEGORY, SIDE, PRICE
```